# How to fix problems with navigating to different pages by ID in a React app?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble navigating to different pages based on ID. I am making a recipe app with the MERN Stack.
I keep getting errors like **No routes matched location "/api/recipes/61f9626a6b8d175f6b6dc725"**

Here is my code:
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import RecipeList from './components/recipes/RecipeList';
import RecipeInfo from './components/recipes/RecipeInfo';
import RecipeAdd from './components/recipes/RecipeAdd';
import RecipeEdit from './components/recipes/RecipeEdit';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <div className="container">
          <Main />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function Navigation() {
  return(
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
      <div className='container'>
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item"><NavLink exact="true" className="nav-link"  to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><NavLink exact="true" className="nav-link"  to="/recipes">Recipes</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

function Main() {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList />} />
      <Route path="/recipes/new" element={<RecipeAdd />} />
      <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<RecipeInfo />} />
      <Route path="/recipes/:id/edit" element={<RecipeEdit />} />
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>

  );
}

export default App;
```

RecipeInfo.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function RecipeInfo(props) {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({});
  const { _id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  useEffect(function() {
    async function getRecipe() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/recipes/${_id}/`);
        setRecipe(response.data);
      } catch(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      }
    }
    getRecipe();
  }, [props, _id]);

  async function handleDelete() {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/recipes/${_id}/`);
      navigate("/api/recipes");
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{recipe.title}</h2>
      <small>_id: {recipe._id}</small>
      <p>{recipe.ingredients}</p>
      <p>{recipe.procedure}</p>
      <div className="btn-group">
        <Link to={`/api/recipes/${recipe._id}/edit`} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
        <button onClick={handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <Link to="/api/recipes" className="btn btn-secondary">Close</Link>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeInfo;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const cors = require('cors');
const router = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;
const MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/recipeDB";

// app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', router);

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected to the Database.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Mongoose Connection Error: ' + error);
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

I am also getting an error saying **error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at postRecipe (RecipeAdd.js:23:1)** Here is the code for that file.

RecipeAdd.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { post } from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";



function RecipeAdd(props) {
  const initialState = { title: '', content: '' }
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState(initialState)
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  function handleChange(event) {
    setRecipe({...recipe, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!recipe.title || !recipe.ingredients || !recipe.procedure) return
    async function postRecipe() {
      try {
        const response = await post('/api/recipes', recipe);
        props.history.push(`/recipes/${response.data._id}`);
      } catch(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      }
    }
    postRecipe();
    navigate("/recipes")
  }

  function handleCancel() {
    navigate("/recipes");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create Recipe</h1>
      <hr/>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input name="title" type="text" value={recipe.title} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Ingredients</label>
          <textarea name="ingredients" rows="5" value={recipe.ingredients} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Procedure</label>
          <textarea name="procedure" rows="5" value={recipe.procedure} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="btn-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary" />
          <button type="button" onClick={handleCancel} className="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecipeAdd;
```

I am fairly new to React, so any advice or best practices I could be doing would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those errors seems to be valid.

Normal navigation around the app do not need to have `/api/*` before. Reason I think is because these are API routes and not navigation routes.

`RecipeInfo.js`

```js
...
 async function handleDelete() {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/recipes/${_id}/`);
      navigate("/recipes");
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
...

return (
    ...
        <Link to={`/recipes/${recipe._id}/edit`} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
        <button onClick={handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <Link to="/recipes" className="btn btn-secondary">Close</Link>
    ...
)
...
```

For the type error. Consider using `navigate` for routing instead of props being passed.

`RecipeAdd.js` line 23

```js
// props.history.push(`/recipes/${response.data._id}`);
navigate(`/recipes/${response.data._id}`);
```